# Compile command works but Run command is not responsive

Tags: c++, runtime-error

Here is my c++ code to read an integer, double it and then print it out on the screen:

```html
#include
<iostream>

  int doubleNumber(int x) { return 2 * x; } int main() { using namespace std; int x; cin >> x; cout
  << doubleNumber(x) << endl; return 0; }
```

I am compiling it using:

```
g++ -o example9 example9.cpp
```

It seems it is fine and it creates the object file but it is impossible to run the file using the following command:

```
./example9
```

In fact it does nothing (not even an error message)

What I am doing incorrectly?
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: try `chmod 700 example9`

Comment: @Ashur What do you mean by "impossible"? Is there an error message? What's the exit code? Did you try running it through a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say it is "impossible to run the file", I expect you are seeing something like the following:

```
$ ./example9
_
```

where I have indicated the cursor position with `_` (just sitting there, on the next line, not doing anything except blinking). In this case, your program is running fine. It is waiting for you to type a number (the `cin >> x` statement). Type a number and press Enter.

Comment: That was true. Thanks, But, it takes two "enters" to do the job.